# Formatting Paragraphs Separately using CSS3

Tags: html, css, validation, formatting, paragraphs

Using CSS3, I can format a single paragraph `<p>` validly.  But when I need multiple paragraphs with different formatting, I rename my paragraphs to `<p1>` and `<p2>`.  I can format them individually, but it does not pass the validity test.  How can I do this in a manner where it will still be valid?

The way I am currently doing it gives me the following errors:

```
Element p1 not allowed as child of element body in this context.
Element p2 not allowed as child of element body in this context.
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't change the element's tag name.

Add a `class` or an `id` to the element in order to differentiate between them.

```
<p class="p1">Paragraph 1</p>

<p class="p2">Paragraph 2</p>
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/P9ZLF/)